# need to convert a object column to int/ float in a Dataframe so that later can do some operations on that

Tags: python

the data set contains Performance_UG which has values of '90.00/100.00' or  '4.0/5.0' or '3.50/4.00' which is stored as object.
now i have to extract the 90 and 100 and divide them and then get the output i.e. 0.9 saved to a new column of the data frame as a float

how do i do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zGsr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming we are talking about pandas here. Each column then should have a [map function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). You can call this on each column and assign it to a new one. Perhaps something like:

```
def parseStuff(x):
    x = x.strip()
    if x == '0':
        return 0
    a, b = [float(i) for i in x.split('/')]
    return a/b

df['Performance_UG_parsed'] = df['Performance_UG'].map(parseStuff))
```

If you want to create new columns or just replace the old one, just iterate over columns or cast it to the same column (although, for same column you can just use apply i think).

Note: You may want to cast it to something other then float, maybe a numpy type if you are working with that stuff.

Comment: Thanks it works with little  modification

def parseStuff(x):

#    x = x.strip()

    if x == 0:

        return 0

    a, b = [float(i) for i in x.split('/')]

    return a/b